# Output odd numbers between 2 integers in C++

Tags: c++

I have completed code that works for the majority of cases for outputting odd numbers between two integers in C++. However it doesn't work for negative numbers and/or if the two values are less than 3 in difference from one another (e.g. it works if the two numbers are 2 & 5, but does not work if the two numbers are 2 & 4).

I know that it is a cause of my code which adds 2 every time the while loop iterates, I'm just not sure how to rectify it.

```
while (secondOddNum - firstOddNum > 2)
    {
        if (firstOddNum % 2 > 0) //positive numbers
        {
            firstOddNum += 2;
            sumOdd += pow(firstOddNum,2);
            cout << firstOddNum << endl;

        } else // even numbers
        {
            firstOddNum += 1;
            sumOdd += pow(firstOddNum,2);
            cout << firstOddNum << endl;
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: Use the `%` module operator. It will return the remainder of a division. i.e. `3%2 == 1`, `2%2 == 0`, `0%2 == 0`, etc..

Comment: Change `>` to `>=`

Comment: @Lauren Curphey if one of the answers below helped you, you should click the checkmark next to it to indicate it is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think your logic is overcomplicating the problem a little bit.  Did you mean to do something like this?

```
void OutputOdds(int min, int max)
{
    for(int i = min; i <= max; i++)
    {
        if(i % 2 == 1 || i % 2 == -1)
            cout << i << " ";
    }
}
```

Tests:

```
OutputOdds(-25, 6);
cout << endl << endl;
OutputOdds(1, 3);
cout << endl << endl;
OutputOdds(2, 4);
```

prints

```
-25 -23 -21 -19 -17 -15 -13 -11 -9 -7 -5 -3 -1 1 3 5 

1 3 

3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
void printOddsBetween(int min, int max) {
  int t = min + (min % 2 == 0);
  while (t <= max) {
    cout << t << endl;
    t += 2;
  }
}
```

It starts at the closest odd value to `min`. Then just prints every odd value up to `max`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  int min = 1;
  int max = 11;
  int counter = 0;
    for (int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
        if (i % 2 != 0) {
            System.out.println(i);
            counter += 1;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("counter" + counter);
    int xx[] = new int[counter];
    int ii = 0;
    for (int i = min; i <= max; i++) {
        if (i % 2 != 0) {
            xx[ii] = i;
            ii += 1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int firstNum{}, secondNum{};

cout << "Enter two numbers, the first smaller than the second."
    << endl;

cout << "Enter first integer: \t";
cin >> firstNum;
cout << endl;

while (firstNum < secondNum);
{
    cout << "Enter second integer: \t";
    cin >> secondNum;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "\nOdd numbers from " << firstNum << " to " << secondNum << " are \n";

    for (int i = firstNum; i <= secondNum; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 != 0)
        {
            cout << i << " ";
        }
    }
}
```

Prints:  **2 & 19 ARE MY USER INPUTS**

Enter two numbers, the first smaller than the second.

Enter first integer:    2

Enter second integer:   19

Odd numbers from 2 to 19 are

3 5 7 9 11 13 15 17 19

Comment: If the question specifically asks for a solution that works for negative numbers, they should be included in the example.